# Angular7 - trying to create table based on content received from api. error : Cannot read property 'StoreLogId' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a table in angular based on a json that I am receiving from an api. but I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'StoreLogId' of undefined

here is the json that I get(the list value that I am using):

```
[{storeLogId: 18, storeId: 2, userId: 10, ip: "192.168.1.15", logType: 1},{storeLogId: 15, storeId: 2, userId: 10, ip: "192.168.1.15", logType: 1}]
```

here is my html that I want to show the table in:

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>StireLogId</th>
          <th>StoreId</th>
          <th>UserId</th>
          <th>LogType</th>
          <th>LogTtext</th>
          <th>CreatedTime</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <tr *ngFor="let response of logsList ; let i = index">
            <td>{{response[i].StoreLogId}}</td>
            <td>{{response[i].StoreId}}</td>
            <td>{{response[i].UserId}}</td>
            <td>{{response[i].LogType}}</td>
            <td>{{response[i].LogTtext}}</td>
            <td>{{response[i].CreatedTime}}</td>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

and this is my service class that I get data from:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  messageForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  success = false;
  logsList ;

  constructor(private data: DataService , private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void  {
    this.data.getAllData(1).subscribe(data => {
      this.logsList = data['obj'];
      console.log(data["obj"]);
    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close try editing to the following. Assuming that the JSON you have added in the question is from the `console.log()` in the subscription, your template should look like this.

**Solution**

```
<tbody>
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let response of logsList ; let i = index">
      <td>{{response.StoreLogId}}</td>
      // other <td> will look the same just changing the accessing value.
  </table>
</tbody>
```

**Explination**

You do not need to add the index when using `*ngFor` to access the values. Check out the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data) on displaying data. You can still run the `*ngFor` with the index coming through, this can be used to easily pass the index of the element in the array to a function and other useful stuff. BR.